# Checking if a URL exists and is smaller than x bytes without consuming full response

Tags: python, django, python-requests, httplib2

I have a use case where I want to check (from within a python/Django project) if a response to a `GET` request is smaller than `x` bytes, if the whole response completes within `y` seconds and if the response status is 200. The URL being tested is submitted by end users.

Some constraints:-

1. `HEAD` request is not acceptable. Simply because some servers might not include a `Content-Length`, or lie about it, or simply block `HEAD` requests.
2. I would not like to consume full `GET` response body. Imagine end user submitting url to 10GB file... all my server bandwidth(and memory) would be consumed by this.

tl;dr : Is there any python http api that:-

1. Accepts a timeout for the whole transaction. (I think httplib2 does this)
2. Response status is 200 (All http libraries do this)
3. Kills the requests(perhaps with `RST`) once `x` bytes have been received to avoid bandwidth starvation.

The `x` here would probably be in order of KBs, `y` would be few seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could open the URL in `urllib` and `read(x+1)` from the returned object. If the length of the returned string is `x+1`, then the resource is larger than `x`. Then call `close()` on the object to close the connection, i.e. kill the request. In the worst case, this will fill the OS's TCP buffer, which is something you can not avoid anyway; usually, this should not fetch more than a few kB more than `x`.

If you furthermore add a [`Range` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.2) to the request, sane servers will close the connection themselves after `x+1` bytes. Note that this changes the reply code to `206 Partial Content`, or `416 Requested range not satisfiable` if the file is too small. Servers which do not support this will ignore the header, so this should be a safe measure.

Comment: Thanks accepting this answer. Im not interested in the Range behaviour. Just interested in what server responds to a simple request. Tested your method works fine for me. The few extra KBs is fine for me.  POC: http://pastie.org/10089931 .